# Is there a light and simple php framework that provides basic localization and/or internationalization?

Tags: php, localization, frameworks

I would like a php framework that:

- Is simple and lightweight
- It work in shared hosting (free hosting)
- I'll be nice if it saves the preferred language using cookies (not necessary)
- I'll be nicer if it detects user's preferred language from the browser (not necessary)

I want to build a page that displays 3 different languages. I came out with a mini localization framework but I think is kinda buggy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go for **[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com)**. However, you can see the complete list of stable php frameworks here:

**http://www.phpframeworks.com**

Comment: Yeah, I've heard good things about CodeIgniter: http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-state-of-web-development-2010-web-directions.